# SQL transform aggregate values into individual columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, transform, transpose

So I have data normalized like this currently:

```
+----------+-------+-------+
| day      | color | value |
+----------+-------+-------+
| 1/1/2016 | red   | 1     |
+----------+-------+-------+
| 1/1/2016 | blue  | 2     |
+----------+-------+-------+
| 1/1/2016 | green | 3     |
+----------+-------+-------+
| 1/2/2016 | red   | 4     |
+----------+-------+-------+
| 1/2/2016 | blue  | 5     |
+----------+-------+-------+
| 1/2/2016 | green | 6     |
+----------+-------+-------+
```

I'd like to transform it into this layout for a report:

```
+----------+-----+------+-------+
| day      | red | blue | green |
+----------+-----+------+-------+
| 1/1/2016 | 1   | 2    | 3     |
+----------+-----+------+-------+
| 1/2/2016 | 4   | 5    | 6     |
+----------+-----+------+-------+
```

The code I'm using to do this is:

```
with
red as (
    select
    day
    ,value as red
    from mytable
    where color='red'
),

blue as (
    select
    day
    ,value as blue
    from mytable
    where color='blue'
),

green as (
    select
    day
    ,value as green
    from mytable
    where color='green'
)

select
red.*
,blue.blue
,green.green
from red red
inner join blue blue
on red.day=blue.day
inner join green green
on red.day=green.day
```

so my question is, is there an easier or less wordy way to do this in Oracle? It seems a little silly for such a simple task! also, it's probably not very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping, i understood your question correctly.

I think below query will help you.

```
select day_col,
max(case when color = 'red' then value_col end) red_color,
max(case when color = 'blue' then value_col end) blue_color,
max(case when color = 'green' then value_col end) green_color
from your_table 
group by day_col;
```

Comment: Better to use `MAX()` than `SUM()` in case his actual dataset has `NULL` values in it.

Comment: ah thanks, i believe this answer is what i'm looking for, but with MAX() like tim said. :)

Comment: sorry, if i got you wrong, just replace sum with max. i have updated the query.